# Correct way to import data from existing database to a newly updated normalized database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have an existing database, that hasn't had any normalization done to it, and its using uniqueidentifiers for Primary Keys. I been tasked with normalizing this database, I guess you could say "overhauling" it.

So I going to do my best to normalize this database without being a DBA, I understand normalization for the most part.

How do I take the existing data and import that into the new database, that is normalized and using autoincremented ids as opposed to uniqueidentifiers?

Comment: With insert statements. Seriously there is no way anybody could possibly answer this. I realize this is a one time data migration but the complexities can get pretty intense here. What happens when you have parent/child tables running 3 or 4 levels deep? This is just entirely too big of a topic for an online forum. We can probably offer some general guidance but even that can get really lengthy.

Comment: The correct way to import data from an existing database to a newly normalized database is **any way you can make it happen**.  Special programs, import / export utilities.

Comment: What @SeanLange said plus maybe before importing into new one, remove any constraints (and corresponding indexes) so that the import is faster, and restore them afterwards.

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe I am going about it the wrong way...maybe instead of trying to import everything, I should just keep the old database and just reference it from the new database and any new data being entered to just go into the new database